# I'm trying to make a canvas move towards another canvas - JAVASCRIPT

Tags: javascript, html, math, canvas

I wrote this code to try to get the myCanvas to move towards myCanvas1. I tried doing this using the Math.atan2() method. However it doesn't work. Any ideas? 
Please don't use any JQuery.

HTML:

```
<canvas id="myCanvas"></canvas>
<canvas id="myCanvas1"></canvas>
```

JS:

```
 var follower = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
    var flw = follower.getContext('2d');

    var runner = document.getElementById('myCanvas1');
    var rnr = runner.getContext('2d');

document.addEventListener('keydown', moveShot);

    //Cordinates of sPositions 1 and two
    var sPosition0 = [700, 700];
    var sPosition1 = [400, 400]; 

    var xPosition0 = sPosition0[0], yPosition0 = sPosition0[1];
    var xPosition1 = sPosition1[0], yPosition1 = sPosition1[1];

    //This should be the arctan between sPosition0 and sPosition1
    var angleRadians0 = Math.atan2(sPosition0[0] - sPosition1[0], sPosition0[1] - Position1[1]);

    /*The speed of the object is 4. To get it to move diagonally towards sPosition1 I need to divide dy with the angle arctan between the two objects */
    var dx = 4;
    var dy = 4 / angleRadians0;

    function moveShot(){
        // Deleting the "old" square
        flw.clearRect(0, 0, 700, 700);
      //Drawing the square at its appropriate position
      flw.fillRect(xPosition0, yPosition0, 100, 100);
      //Adding the movement after every frame
      xPosition0 += dx;
      yPosition0 += dy;
      setTimeout(moveShot, 20);
    }
```

CSS:

```
#myCanvas1{
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: '#ff0000';
}
```

Thanks!

EDIT: 
As to what actually happens, I'm very confused. Nothing happens at all, I didn't say that because it's 3am and I thought someone would point out some very obvious mistake I've made and everything would make sence. So, what happens is well, nothing, I cannot understand why. Then again though, its 3am and I might have screwed up somewhere but I don't see where.

Here's a fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/Snubben/15tf0svd/3/

Comment: You have stated what you expect to happen, but not what actually happens. Could you add more details so that people can offer help with less effort?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to move? You have multiple canvas' and your moveShot function appears to be moving a square that is already inside the first canvas, making the second obsolete. ...

Answer (score 0):

Well, the reason NOTHING happens, is that your canvas is using the default size. 300x150;

Your initial position is drawing the square OUTSIDE the canvas, and then your dx and dy variables are adding to x and y, making it move even further away (down and to the right).

See the following for an example of keeping it within the container and moving the square up and to the left.

```js
var follower = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
var flw = follower.getContext('2d');

var runner = document.getElementById('myCanvas1');
var rnr = runner.getContext('2d');

document.addEventListener('keydown', moveShot);

//Cordinates of sPositions 1 and two
var sPosition0 = [70, 70]; //within the canvas
var sPosition1 = [40, 40]; //within the canvas

var xPosition0 = sPosition0[0],
  yPosition0 = sPosition0[1];
var xPosition1 = sPosition1[0],
  yPosition1 = sPosition1[1];

//This should be the arctan between sPosition0 and sPosition1
var angleRadians0 = Math.atan2(sPosition0[0] - sPosition1[0], sPosition0[1] - sPosition1[1]);

/*The speed of the object is 4. To get it to move diagonally towards sPosition1 I need to divide dy with the angle arctan between the two objects */
var dx = 4;
var dy = 4 / angleRadians0;

function moveShot() {
   if(yPosition0 < 10) return;
  // Deleting the "old" square
  flw.fillStyle = "green";
  flw.clearRect(0, 0, 700, 700);

  //Drawing the square at its appropriate position
  flw.fillRect(xPosition0, yPosition0, 10, 10); 

  //Adding the movement after every frame
  xPosition0 -= dx; //move left
  yPosition0 -= dy; //move up.
  setTimeout(moveShot, 20);
}
```

```css
#myCanvas1 {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: #ff0000;
}

#myCanvas {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="myCanvas" height="300" width="300"></canvas>
<canvas id="myCanvas1" height="100" width="100"></canvas>
```

press a key to make it work.